# how to get form values h1, p in node js server side as like input

Tags: html, node.js

post the form to the node js server

```
<form action="/anchor" method="post" >
      <h5>Author: Julian Hansen, April 2017</h5>
      <input type="text" name="username" > 
</form>
```

```
app.post("/anchor",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.val);
});
```

how can access the h5 inner value here in the node js server as like input elements(req.body)

Comment: Add a hidden input to the form `<input type='hidden' name='author' value='Julian' />`

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to whatever element you want to access and you can access it by using `req.body.[id]` on the server side.